# how to clear ArrayAdapter with custom ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

this is how I add items to the ListView:

```
public class ServersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public ServersAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] servers) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, servers);
        Log.d("noc", "ServersAdapterin: ");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d("noc", "getView: ");

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.servers_list, parent, false);

        Log.d("noc", "inflate: ");
        //datasource = new ServersDataSource(getContext());
        datasource.open();
        //servir list
        Log.d("noc", "ServersDataSource: ");
        Server[] servers = datasource.getAllServers();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Log.d("noc", "setText: ");
        if (servers.length > 0) {
            tv.setText(servers[position].getTitle());
            Log.d("noc", "getTitle: ");

            Log.d("noc", "servers[position].getTitle()-==================: "+ servers[position].getTitle());
            if (servers[position].getEnabled() < 1) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_server_status_red);
            } else {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_server_status_green);
            }
        }
        return row;

    }
}
```

this is the onCreate:

```
......
try {

        Log.d("noc", "need to delete this: ");
        datasource = new ServersDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        //servir list
        Log.d("noc", "servir list: ");
        //String[] servers = new String[10];
        //servir list
        Log.d("noc", "ServersDataSource: ");
        String[] servers = new String[10];


        Log.d("noc", "end need to delete this");
        ArrayAdapter<Server> adapter = new ServersAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textView1, servers);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("noc", "error (ArrayAdapter): " + e.toString());
    }
```

I am unable to clear a ListView from all of its content (I'm trying to empty it). I have been trying to do so like so:

```
ArrayAdapter<Server> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Server>) getListAdapter();
Server server = null;
switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.add:
        // Save the new server to the database
        // server_id, "title", "url", "ip", enabled, "services", fetch_interval
        server = datasource.createServer(1, "title of the server", "url of the server", "ip of the server", 1, "services of the server", 1);
        adapter.add(server);
        break;
    case R.id.delete:
        Log.d("noc", "delete ");
        if (getListAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
            datasource.emptyServersTable();
            Log.d("noc", "clear ");
            adapter.clear();
            Log.d("noc", "after clear ");

        }
        break;
    }
    Log.d("noc", "notifyDataSetChanged");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and this is the output when  click "delete":

```
01-11 23:41:54.210: D/noc(14898): delete 
01-11 23:41:54.210: D/noc(14898): emptyServersTable: 
01-11 23:41:54.230: D/noc(14898): clear 
01-11 23:41:54.230: D/AndroidRuntime(14898): Shutting down VM
01-11 23:41:54.230: W/dalvikvm(14898): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4140e2a0)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3699)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3694)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    ... 11 more
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:638)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.remove(AbstractList.java:75)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:658)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:466)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear(ArrayAdapter.java:258)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    at com.wr.noc.ServersStatus.onClick(ServersStatus.java:91)
01-11 23:41:54.230: E/AndroidRuntime(14898):    ... 14 more
```

so what is the problem. is there another way to do so?

Comment: Are you passing off an Array to the adapter or an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Post how you create your ArrayAdapter, does it use primitive Array?

Comment: did you try calling `setListAdapter(null);` instead of `clear`

Comment: How did you create ArrayAdapter, you might be using an immutable list to back it.

Comment: @dmon He probably passed an array as that is transformed into a special list for which remove isn't implemented.

Comment: Use a list of Strings instead of the array of Strings and the `clear` method will work.

Comment: I have re-edited my question and added the onCreate. I am still unable to resolve this issue. any other ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try to override the `clear()` method in the `ServersAdapter` class and add a call to the `clear()` method of your `ArrayList` if you have one. If your data is loaded into views from an array just empty it.

Looking at your code I think the concerned one is **servers**.

Comment: i am using an ArrayAdapter not an ArrayList

Comment: Yeah but the `ArrayAdapter` is not supposed to hold the data, often the `Adapter` contains an `ArrayList`, or a normal array, and then put the data of each object of the array into the views created in the `getView()` using the int **position** to get the data at this index in the array/ArrayList.

Comment: Currently it doesn't work because in your constructor you pass a `String[]` array which is not the one that hold the data you want to load into views. Just pass the array that you use in the `getView()` method wich is called **servers** and then use the index to get the data at this position in the array.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you passed a List or an Array to the Adapter. If you keep the instance of this added items, you can do a:

```
adapter.clear();
listview.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Not all Adapters have a `clear()` method. ArrayAdapter does, but `ListAdapter` or `SimpleAdapter` don't

Comment: can I do what you recommend. I have edited my question with some more coding.

Comment: I don't think .notifyDataSetChanged() is a valid method call here. It doesn't work in this instance it seems.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation for that constructor (the one with the array) does `Arrays.asList(objects)` which creates an immutable list. Try passing in an explicit ArrayList with your Strings to this constructor:

```
  public ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, 
                      int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge there is  no need to clear adapter and set notifyDataSetChanged() to the adapter.
u have used List,ArrayList For the item or the Array 1 st clear it and reinitialize it and After passing the data to costume adapter clear the used array/list.It will working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it removes all items from the View

```
    final int adapterCount = adapter.getCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapterCount; i++) {
        View item = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
        myLayout.removeView(item);
    }
```